# Thisworkbook.path & "\" returns error 76

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am getting a file not found error when I click this button.
It's an xml file that takes inputs and spits out another xml file in a format that another program uses and uses sample files to build it. I'm a technician, not a programmer and am having trouble getting this to work.

The line

```
FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + "sample 800A.xml", xmfile
```

is the one that gives me an error, but my understanding is that I shouldn't get a file not found error if I have an xml file called sample 800A in the same folder as this workbook. I put all the code in for the button for context.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
r = ActiveCell.Row
'folder = Cells(r, 1).Text + ". " + Cells(r, 4).Text + "+" + Cells(r,   5).Text + "." + Cells(r, 6).Text
'pathfolder = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + folder

'MkDir (pathfolder)

xmfile = Cells(r, 4).Text + "-" + Cells(r, 5).Text + "." + Cells(r, 6).Text + "-Static Feeder.xml"
del = Left(xmfile, 5)
xmfile = Replace(xmfile, del, "\" + Cells(r, 1).Text + ". ")

xmfile = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\00. XML Files" + xmfile 'xmfile2 = pathfolder + "\test.xml"

PUs = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor_Math(1.08 * Cells(r, 15) * Cells(r, 12), 10)
PUe = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Math(1.08 * Cells(r, 15) *     Cells(r, 12), 10)
 OL1 = Cells(r, 20).Text
OL2 = Cells(r, 22).Text
STL = Cells(r, 24).Text
GND = Cells(r, 26).Text

If Cells(r, 11) > 2 Then
FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + "sample 800A.xml", xmfile
End If

If Cells(r, 11) <= 2 Then
FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Path + "\" + "sample 6A.xml", xmfile
End If

Open xmfile For Input As #1
Dim Textline As String
Do While Not EOF(1)
Line Input #1, Textline
Loop

If Cells(r, 11) > 2 Then
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">111<", ">" + Str(PUs) + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">112<", ">" + Str(PUe) + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">222<", ">" + OL1 + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">333<", ">" + OL2 + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">444<", ">" + STL + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">555<", ">" + GND + "<")
End If

If Cells(r, 11) <= 2 Then
PUs = 1.13 * Cells(r, 14)
PUe = 1.17 * Cells(r, 14)
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">1.11<", ">" + Str(PUs) + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">1.12<", ">" + Str(PUe) + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">2.22<", ">" + OL1 + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">3.33<", ">" + OL2 + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">4.44<", ">" + STL + "<")
Textline = Replace(Textline, ">5.55<", ">" + UNB + "<")
End If


Close #1
Open xmfile For Output As #1
Print #1, Textline

Close #1
MsgBox ("CPC XML file created for " + xmfile)

End Sub
```

Comment: is the xml file named sample 800.xml or is it named sample 800A.xml

Comment: Sorry, yes it is named sample 800A

Comment: Replace the "+"s with "&"s.  "+" is only for arithmetic.  "&" is to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
FileCopy ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "sample 800A.xml", xmfile
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you don't have access to the file. It's not really written anywhere (that I could find easily) but the "File Not Found" error also shows up if the user can't modify the file. Because with respect to the current user, the file doesn't exist.

Make sure the user can access the file and make changes to it without the windows UAC (user account control) warning popping up. If they cant change it, this copy would also fail

**edit**

actually after reading your question again i realized something is wrong. I don't think the filecopy is throwing the error. We see from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s1c774y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) filecopy throws errors 52,55,53(file not found). You see an error 76? this is usually associated with mkDir call. but your mkDir is commented out. are you sure xmfile is exactly what you want it to be? One tricky thing about file copy is it fails if the destination directory doesn't exists. You couldn't do

```
Call FileCopy("c:\somefile.txt","c:\a\difffilename.txt")
```

if directory "c:\a" doesn't exist

Sometimes where vba stops isn't always where the error occurs, it's weird that way